# Are there downsides from opening a SQL Connection 50k times on separate threads?

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, parallel-processing

I want to know if there is a better recommended way to do this. My DBA has notified me that this below code is causing Page Latches and Page Waits in production and eventual timeouts. I have to process as many messages that arrive in a messaging server. The only way I could figure to do this is through loops and threading. Each thread will open a new connection to SQL and pass an xml list of data.

I am not sure why he is saying page waits are happening as I though SQL could handle millions of connections. Could it be the connection string itself? I am closing my connections but any advice here would help. Thank you

Here is the connection string. I have the pool to 10k as without it I get pool exhaustion errors. I could lower the value to maybe 1000 but I am not sure if this even makes a difference.

```
  var connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Asynchronous Processing=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=10000;Min Pool Size=100;"
```

Here is an example of the threads. I chose 50k here but it could be upwards of 100k messages in the queue at peak hours.

```
  var results = Enumerable.Range(0, 50000)
                         .AsParallel()
                         .WithDegreeofParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                         .Select(x => InsertPayloadtoDB(xmlList))
                         .ToList()
```

The payload is an XML that is sent to the stored procedure for processing.

```
public void InsertPayloadtoDB(XmlElement xmlList)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await ExecuteNonQueryAsync("MyStoredProcedure",
        new List<SqlParameter>{ new SqlParameter("@xmlList", xmlList.ToString())}));
}

public static Task<bool> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(string storedProcedureName,
    List<SqlParameter> parameters) 
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the Stored Procedure which just takes what I send it and inserts into a table.

```
DECLARE @xmlList = NULL

BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
                     (
                         First varchar(40),
                         Last varchar(40),
                         Address varchar(50),
                         -- ... 15 more columns
                     )

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO @MyTable (First varchar(40),
                              Last varchar(40),
                              Address varchar(50),
                              --... 15 more columns
                             )
            SELECT
                N.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(40)') AS Name
                N.value('(Last)[1]', 'varchar(40)') AS Last
                N.value('(Address)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Address
            FROM
                @xmlList.nodes('//ClientInfo') AS T(N)

        // This is where the deadlock seems to happen as when 
        // I comment this out everything is smooth sailing. 
        INSERT INTO ClientInfoTable (Name, Last, Address, ...)
            SELECT
                Name, Last,
                Address,
                ...
            FROM @MyTable
       )

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: FYI, the max number of connections per SQL instance is 32K, not millions. 10K concurrent active threads seems a lot but much depends on the SQL Server compute and storage. There's not much value in throwing more work at the db server than it can service. I suggest json rather than XML for lists.

Comment: If the proc is just inserting rows, I suspect you'll get better throughput with fewer threads and larger payloads. How many instances of your service are you running?

Comment: Why are you using a table variable in the procedure? Just use a derived table or CTE.

Comment: You should probably rethink this: perhaps upload all the XML at once and process it in one batch. Agreed you should probably use a TVP or JSON for this instead of XML, or possibly `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I will changed from to a TVP. I can create a user defined table and just send that over. 

Also I wish I could do larger payloads in batches but the messages have to be processed as they come in as quickly as possible.

Comment: Maybe this is a pared down example, but why shred the XML on your very expensive database server and not application side? Also, the transaction in your stored procedure doesn't really do much. Operations on table variables don't obey transactional semantics and so only the insert statement is really "protected" by the transaction. But since all statements run inside of an implicit transaction, you didn't really buy much with the explicit transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `Pooling=True` so the `SqlConnection.Open()` fetches an already-open connection from the connection pool and `SqlConnection.Close()` returns it to the pool.

And you've got `.WithDegreeofParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)` so a modest number of threads will be using connections at any one time.

But you've got a nice, moderate parallel loop, but you're firing off all the tasks at once.  Basically you don't need both a parallel loop *and* async tasks.  Just use syncronous code on your threads.  Eg

```
    public void InsertPayloadtoDB(XmlElement xmlList)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlList", xmlList.ToString()) );
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

You might also reduce the number of threads further, or perform a brief sleep after each message to reduce the load on the server if it's still too high.

Comment: Did you noticed the fire-and-forget task in the `InsertPayloadtoDB` method?

Comment: Yikes.  updated answer.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Ok I will change into sync. So each thread will have one synchronous insert. Should I also change the connection string? Is MARS an issue? Is having the pool at 10k for each thread an issue?

Comment: Your connection pool will never have more connections than you have threads here.  The default pool size of 100 should be more than sufficient, as the number of parallel threads should be small.

Comment: Thanks I will go with it along with the other comments. Thank you all

Comment: @CodeMan03, additionally, it is possible to significantly improve performance of your stored procedure. Just ask a separate new question about it,

Comment: @CodeMan03, the technique I've successfully used for high-volume messages is not a fixed-sized batch, but the lesser of a configurable max batch size (e.g. 1000) or maximum latency (e.g. 1 second). This will greatly reduce the number of round trips, transactions, resource utilization, and provide better throughput.